# Spring Boot - Central db Connection for multiple microservices application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, microservices

Hello stackoverflowers!

So I am working on spring boot microservices and following scenario came up:

I have follwing services:

- user-services
- admin-services
- financial-services

and couple more..

I have spring-cloud where all my apps are reading configs from in combination with Eureka as discovery and Zuul as gateway servers.

Here's the scenario, the database is only one (very old legacy one) which we can't break into multiple dbs per microservice app (as per true microservice concepts). Now when all these apps will be started (most probably 2 instances per service) so there will be around 30 opened connections on the db. Is there a way to use a common database layer since there is only one db and all the apps configured to that layer?

Comment: Make a single DB microservice and all the apps call it?

Comment: @csmckelvey, thanks for responding. Can you provide with any examples?